# Proving the limit of $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\prod_{n}^{i=1}\left ( 1+\frac{i^{p}}{n^{p+1}} \right )= e^{\frac{1}{p+1}}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

How to proof   $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left ( 1+\frac{i^{p}}{n^{p+1}} \right )= e^{\frac{1}{p+1}}\left ( p> 0 \right )$   ?
I know $\lim_{x\rightarrow\infty}(1+\frac 1 x)^x=e$, but I don't know how to use it  to proof this problem. Should I use the Squeeze theorem or anything else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the inequality $x-\frac{x^2}{2} \leq \log(1+x) \leq x$ which holds for $0 \leq x \leq 1$, we  can check that

$$ \sum_{i=1}^{n} \left( \frac{i^p}{n^{p+1}} - \frac{i^{2p}}{2n^{2p+2}}\right) \leq \log\left(\prod_{i=1}^{n}\left(1+\frac{i^p}{n^{p+1}}\right)\right) \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{i^p}{n^{p+1}}. $$

Recognizing both bounds as Riemann sums, it follows that both converge to $\int_{0}^{1} x^p \, \mathrm{d}x = \frac{1}{1+p}$ as $n\to\infty$. Then the conclusion follows from the squeezing lemma.